# sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `\'

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have written a script that takes a txt file from a folder and I want to insert a blank line at the end of the file, and then write to it.
But I have a problem, because the console returns: sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `'.

This is code:

```
adb shell "sudo cp /boot/uEnv.txt /home/rock/"
adb shell "sudo sed -i '$s/$/\n/' /home/rock/uEnv.txt"
adb shell "sudo sed -i '$i extraargs=rtl8723ds.rtw_initmac=\"MACAUXTXT\"' /home/rock/uEnv.txt"
adb shell "sudo sed -i "s/MACAUXTXT/$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address | sed 's/.\{9\}//' | sed 's/^/00:e0:4c:/' )/" /home/rock/uEnv.txt"
adb shell "sudo cp /home/rock/uEnv.txt /boot/"
adb shell "sudo cp /home/rock/Service/20-rock.conf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/"
adb shell "sudo rm /home/rock/Service/rockpi-backup.sh"
adb shell "sudo rm /home/rock/Service/20-rock.conf"
adb shell "sudo rm /home/rock/uEnv.txt"
```

This is problem: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgUi0.png)

Comment: Which command is producing that error? You can leave all the rest out of the question, they're irrelevant.

Comment: If you don't know, put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. It will show each line as it's executed, then you'll see which one is before the error message.

Comment: Please show your problem in your question and no image.

Comment: I think that you have succeeded in adding a newline to your copied file. Have you checked whether your file has the extra newline? So what does the error prevent you from doing? Do you know? Have you checked?

Comment: @Barmar the command is the adb shell "sudo sed -i '$s/$/\n/' /home/rock/uEnv.txt", it is returning the error.

Comment: @Larry yes I checked uEnv.txt and saw that I am not able to add a line in the file, exactly because of the error: sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `\'.

This error appears as a return from the adb shell command "sudo sed -i '$s/$/\n/' /home/rock/uEnv.txt"

Comment: Thanks, your answer actually immediately makes the question answerable. @Barmar's response is the key, which you have now answered.

Comment: Please edit the question to narrow it down to the command with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with nested quoting:

`adb shell "sudo sed -i '$s/$/\n/' /home/rock/uEnv.txt"`

The shell that runs the `adb` command processes all of its arguments, including the `sudo ...` part in double quotes. Since double quotes allow variable expansion by the shell, `$s` is expanded before `sed` or even `sudo` is executed.
Depending on what you have stored in the variable named `s`, it is substituted and finally processed by `sed`. If you don't have an `s` variable, an empty string is substituted and `$s` disappears.

You can see for yourself if you substitute `echo` for `adb`:

`echo shell "sudo sed -i '$s/$/\n/' /home/rock/uEnv.txt"`

**shell sudo sed -i '/$/\n/' /home/rock/uEnv.txt**

Now `sed`'s middle argument is `/$/\n/` instead of `$s/$/\n/`. `/$/` is interpreted as a regular expression filter to decide which lines to operate on, and `\n/` as the command and its arguments. Since `\` is not a valid command, you get the error described.

There are several ways to go about this.

I can't name a good solution off the top of my head, but one solution is to escape the dollar sign in the top-most shell so it is passed untouched to the subshell:

`adb shell "sudo sed -i '\$s/\$/\n/' /home/rock/uEnv.txt"`

I escaped the second dollar symbol for good measure as well, although in your case, it has no effect. It is not substituted, because `/` is not a legal variable name. However, if you later decided to e.g. change the `sed` command's separator to `#` to, for instance, deal with file names in the pattern or substitution string, the second dollar symbol would already become a problem, because `#` is the name of the argument-count shell variable.